# VB.NET - Check if child node if checked in TreeView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, treeview

I am using Visual Basic .NET 2013 and I want to know which child nodes are checked in a treeview. I don't check parent nodes because the checkboxes are only in child nodes (I have disabled checkboxes in parent nodes, so they don't appear).

At the moment I am using one solution I found:

```
Private Sub TreeView1_AfterCheck(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterCheck
    Dim childNodeCK As TreeNode = e.Node

    If childNodeCK.Checked = True Then
        If e.Node.Parent Is Nothing = False Then 'detects a Child Node
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & childNodeCK.Text
            MessageBox.Show("Checked: " & childNodeCK.Text)
        End If
    End If

    If childNodeCK.Checked = False Then
        If e.Node.Parent Is Nothing = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Unchecked: " & childNodeCK.Text)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

But I want to know if there is another solution, something like this (the following code doesn't show anything because when I click a button to run it, nothing happens):

```
For Each childNode As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode In TreeView1.Nodes
        If childNode.Checked = True Then
            MessageBox.Show(childNode.Text)
        End If 
Next
```

because the idea is to click a button and obtain the name (text) of the child nodes that are checked at that moment. So I think I have to check one by one from the beginning to the end and if the child node is checked then execute some code.

Comment: `TreeView1.Nodes` only gives you the root nodes in the tree.  You would have to specify the parent node and use the Nodes collections from that to check your child nodes.  Or are you asking to get ALL nodes in the tree that are checked?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have 3 root nodes and each root node has its own child nodes:
-Root node #1
   --Child node #1
   --Child node #2
   --Child node #3
-Root node #2
   --Child node #1
   --Child node #2
-Root node #3
   --Child node #1
   --Child node #2
   --Child node #3

I want to check all the child nodes that exist in the treeview. In the example I have just detailed, there are 8 child nodes. So I want to get ALL nodes in the tree that are checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all of the checked nodes, you would have to use a recursive function or a stacked list.  I prefer the latter:

```
Private Function GetCheckedNodes() As List(Of TreeNode)
  Dim result As New List(Of TreeNode)

  'Get the root nodes
  Dim nodes As New Stack(Of TreeNode)
  For Each tn As TreeNode In TreeView1.Nodes
    nodes.Push(tn)
  Next

  'Check each node and it's children
  While nodes.Count > 0
    Dim popNode As TreeNode = nodes.Pop
    If popNode.Checked Then
      result.Add(popNode)
    End If
    For Each tn As TreeNode In popNode.Nodes
      nodes.Push(tn)
    Next
  End While

  Return result
End Function
```

Then to use it:

```
For Each tn As TreeNode In GetCheckedNodes()
  MessageBox.Show(tn.Text)
Next
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Really appreciated. Thank you very much. I am now examining carefully the code to learn the parts that I have never worked with.

Comment: @RichardSteele Push puts the node into the list, Pop takes it out.

Comment: Yes, I see. I have been testing the code to know more about the new characteristics I didn't know and I have learned a lot while examining the code. Thank you very much.